# 2001-01-01 00:00:00.000 inserted into database instead 2000-12-31 23:59:59

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, datetime

I have a method which adds row to database (sql server 2005). Something is wrong with its because , when I have a row with UpdateDate `2000-12-31 23:59:59`  it inserts `2001-01-01 00:00:00.000`. Is it possible? Culture of environment is polish if it is important. It's a magic for me :/

```
private void AddInvestmentStatus(InvestmentData.StatusyInwestycjiRow investmentStatusesRow)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("AddInvestmentStatus");
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


    SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter("@InvestmentId", SqlDbType.BigInt);
    param1.Value = investmentStatusesRow.InvestmentId;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(param1);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enumInvestmentStatusID", investmentStatusesRow.EnumInvestmentStatusID);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@modifiedBy", "System");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UpdateDate", investmentStatusesRow.UpdateDate);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ModifiedOn", investmentStatusesRow.ModifiedOn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dataVersion", investmentStatusesRow.DataVersion);


    cmd.Connection = new SqlConnection(MyProgram.Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString);
    if (cmd.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        cmd.Connection.Open();

    try
    {
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

}

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddInvestmentStatus] 
    @inwestmentID bigint,
    @enumInvestmentStatusId bigint,
    @updateDate datetime,
    @dataVersion int,
    @modifiedBy nvarchar(50),
    @modifiedOn datetime
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @investmentStatusesID bigint

    INSERT INTO StatusyInwestycji(InwestycjaID)
    VALUES (@inwestmentID)

    SELECT @investmentStatusesID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

    INSERT INTO StatusyInwestycjiData(InvestmentStatusId, EnumStatusInwestycjiID,
            UpdateDate, DataVersion, ModifiedBy, ModifiedOn)
    VALUES (@investmentStatusesID, @enumInvestmentStatusId,
            @updateDate, @dataVersion, @modifiedBy, @modifiedOn)

END
```

EDIT:

my date:

```
{2000-12-31 22:59:59}
    Date: {2000-12-31 00:00:00}
    Day: 31
    DayOfWeek: Sunday
    DayOfYear: 366
    Hour: 22
    Kind: Utc
    Millisecond: 999
    Minute: 59
    Month: 12
    Second: 59
    Ticks: 631139003999990000
    TimeOfDay: {22:59:59.9990000}
    Year: 2000
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity (I don't know anything about C#): What does that `try/catch` block do? It looks like it catches any exception and re-raises (throws?) it right away? What am I missing?

Comment: @Tim - you aren't missing anything; your observation is correct. What is missing is a few `using`... the `try`/`catch`/`throw` does nothing (except maybe as somewhere to stick a break-point in debug mode)

Comment: Yes, you have right. It's easier to debug, when I have this block.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Are you sure you're entering 23:59:59.000000 or are you entering 23:59:59.9999999?

SQL DateTime datatype has precision of 3.33ms (it will round to 0ms, 3ms, 7ms increments), meaning your 23:59:59.9999 will be rounded to 00:00:00.000000 of the next day.

Comment: so to fix it, I must minus 4 milisecunds, yes?

Comment: Yes, that will work. Also, SQL 2008 has a DateTime2 which has the precision of 1ms, so you can keep that in mind if you migrate.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this is what happens in your case, but it's a known issue that datetime values where the millisecond portion is .998 or .999 get rounded to the next whole second value when inserted in the database, which in the worst case scenario can lead a datetime value to wrap into the following year.

Answer (score 3):

If the table has a smalldatetime column it is possible, since it has precision of 1 minute

see here

```
select CONVERT(smalldatetime,'2000-12-31 23:59:59')
```

doesn't happen with datetime

```
select CONVERT(datetime,'2000-12-31 23:59:59')
```

Post the DDL of the table, make sure to also check for triggers that might me casting to smalldatetime

Comment: It is a datetime (not smalldatetime)

Comment: script out the table and verify that it is a datetime, are there triggers on the table?